# block the flow of javascript

Tags: javascript

If I write:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return 'exit?' ;};
```

I get a popup to stay / leave the page.
you can create a custom pop-up in html?

the problem is this:
if I create a popup html, which is activated only when you exit from the current page, and I will see him for half a second, then change page ... how can I fix this?
I need something (like the command alert) I block the page until you press a button.

Comment: it would be polite to accept some answers for your previous questions

Comment: There are modal dialogs in jQuery and almost every other framework.

Comment: as far as im aware you can't fully stop the browser on navigating away, the only way is the built in `return "exit?"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.  Which is good, because it would be *really damn irritating* if every website could stop me from browsing away from the page until they felt like it.

`onbeforeunload` is the only mechanism you've got.  It ensures the browser still has enough control to let me leave if I want to, and prevents you from sticking me in an `alert` loop or similar.

Comment: instead then you can enter your own text in the popup and link?

Comment: the string you return from `onbeforeunload` will show in the popup, yes.  but that's all you get: a single plain string, no HTML.